# Getting a 500 status code from "oauth2/token" AWS endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, saml

```
POST https://[CLIENT].auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token

x-www-form-urlencoded body params:

grant_type: authorization_code

code: bec8b238-f3c9-4db2-bb03-51047f7aaab6

redirect_uri: https://[DOMAIN].com/ssoLogin?acid=[ACID]

client_id: [CLIENT_ID]
```

Here's the set up for the call and we receive a 500 with a response

`{"error": "Internal Error"}`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html We've been following with these docs.  This userpool does not have a client secret.